# Delphi iOS reuse launch image for app background

Tags: ios, delphi

I wish to reuse the launch images as backgrounds for my app. Currently I am doing something like this:

```
procedure TFormMain.InitRepeat_Background;
var
  P: string;
  R: TMyRetrieveFileResult;
begin
  P := '';
  if ((P = '') and (FScreenOrientation = TScreenOrientation.soPortrait)) then
    begin
      P := 'app_background_480x800.png';
    end
  ;
  if ((P = '') and (FScreenOrientation = TScreenOrientation.soLandscape)) then
    begin
      P := 'app_background_800x480.png';
    end
  ;
  if (P <> '')then
    begin
      R := TMyRetrieveFileResult.Create(FBitmapBuffer, '', 0, -1);
      ReadGenericBitmapOffline(R, '', P);
      if R.Found then
        begin
          ImageBackground.Bitmap.Assign(R.BitmapRef);
          ImageBackground.WrapMode := TImageWrapMode.iwStretch;
        end
      ;
    end
  ;
end;
```

However, the stretch thing is not the prettiest (not the ugliest either, but still). Is there any way I can detect the best background image to show (from the "launch images pool") as background?

I guess I could either try detect specific device or... Try detect closest screen resolution? Or maybe there is an API I can use (whatever Delphi uses to select launch image on startup?)

Comment: Hi Tom, not sure if it will work under FM (my copy of XE4 hasn't arrived yet) but you should be able to detect screen resolution from the form's ClientHeight and ClientWidth properties. Once you've got that you should then be able to determine the best image to load.

Comment: I am contemplating doing this as well, but I am going to try find out (so far unsuccessfully) how Delphi is doing it to see if there is more to it than that.

Comment: The title of this question says it's about re-using images. Is that really what it's about, though? It seems to be about choosing an image appropriate for the size and orientation of the screen. If *that's* what you want to know about, then maybe you could reword your question and title to make *that* more apparent. Leave out irrelevant details.

Comment: @RobKennedy Well, I want to use the eaact same images (instead of my own provided as I do now) that is shown during startup. The reason for this is 1) looks better to use one that matches dimensions 100% 2) to obey Apple iOS guidelines better. (So the app background is exactly the same as the one shown during launch)

Comment: I would kinda like to award the bounty... :)