# finding placement where launch images are stored

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe4, delphi-xe6

The deployment page states launch images are stored in root.

However, all of the following paths return false when using **FileExists** so...

```
FileExists(TPath.GetHomePath + PathDelim + 'LaunchImage_320x480.png');
FileExists(TPath.GetHomePath + PathDelim + Application.Title + '.app' + PathDelim + 'LaunchImage_320x480.png'); 
FileExists(TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + 'LaunchImage_320x480.png');
FileExists('' + 'LaunchImage_320x480.png');
FileExists('.\' + 'LaunchImage_320x480.png');
```

Comment: It's just "filename". No path. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to load the launch image into a TBitmap. For that I need the (full) path to where they are stored. It is for this SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994429/delphi-ios-reuse-launch-image-for-app-background

Comment: Please always add the delphi tag to your question and avoid those tags in title

Comment: Did you try what Marcus suggested (simply `FileExists(FileName)`)?

Comment: @KenWhite I just tried FileExists on just the filename and that yields false as well. (Would also be a so-so solution since afaik that uses getcurrentdirectory? or something like that. But if it had worked, I could of coruse have seen and gotten the correct directory through that.)

Comment: Root in this case does not refer to the root of the drive, but the root of the application, ie the application's folder in "C:\program files" or "C:\program files (x86)" Or whatever they would be on iOS.

Comment: If anyone happens to know where launch images are stored, it would be great :)

Comment: I have put a bounty on the question now since it remains unsolved.

Comment: @Tom I have successfully created a full image based app on iOS using Delphi XE6. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The launch images should be stored in the same folder as the application as described by the documentation. You should be able to get the filename using NSBundle.pathForResource.

```
uses
  iOSapi.Foundation, Macapi.Helpers;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  FileName: string;
begin
  FileName := NSStrToStr(TNSBundle.Wrap(TNSBundle.OCClass.mainBundle).pathForResource(NSSTR('Default'), NSStr('png')));
  //....
end;
```

The trick might be that the filenames of the launch image are not necessarily identical to those in the IDE. You could list all the files in your application like this:

```
uses
  iOSapi.Foundation, Macapi.Helpers, System.IOUtils;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FileName: string;
  files: TStringDynArray;
  AppFolder: string;
  I: Integer;
begin
  AppFolder := NSStrToStr((TNSBundle.Wrap(TNSBundle.OCClass.mainBundle).bundlePath));
  Files := TDirectory.GetFiles(AppFolder);
  for I := 0 to Length(Files) - 1 do
    Memo1.Lines.Add(ExtractFileName(Files[I]));
end;
```

You could also use a tool like DiskAid in order to take a look at the iOS application folder on Windows.

Comment: I have let Delphi add the launch images through the project options - they work during the app launch. Unfortunately I get *nil* when trying your code:      
        TNSBundle.Wrap
        (
          TNSBundle.OCClass.mainBundle
        ).pathForResource
        (
          NSSTR('LaunchImage_320x480')
          ,
          NSSTR('png')
        )
      ;

Comment: DiskAid did not show any files at all under my app :(

Comment: You might have to change the preferences in DiskAid so it shows the root folder of your application. But I think the missing piece is that the launch image is not necessarily called LaunchImage.... I've updated this in my answer.

Comment: After you mentioned the options, I tried again with DiskAid, so it shows hidden folders/files and the app root. (Thanks a lot for the DiskAid tip. Huge timeserver when investigating!) I still can not find the launch images though. I am starting to think they perhaps are compiled into the Delphi generated app-executable or something like that?

Comment: I do get the launch images as separate files, but they're called Default*.png and not LaunchImage*.png. I already changed that in my example code. If you still don't see them, open all the images and see which ones are the launch images.

Comment: When looking in DiskAid there are no images at all. Neither "Default_", "LaunchImage_" or "FM_" - maybe because DiskAid won't show the file. I will try your code and report back!

Comment: DiskAid never showed any images, but your code iterating image files does. And you are correct, I had remote image names incorrect. (I can see changing remote names in Delphi do not stick. Doh! Mistake by me.) Thanks again! This problem has actually nagged me for quite a while! Answer accepted + bounty awarded :)

Answer (score 1):

The default images are stored at this directory (you can find it using a terminal on MacOS)

```
DirPath := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetHomePath, Application.Title + '.app');
```

.

If you are asking for how to locate self-upload files, 
**Here is the instruction:**

1. Click `Project` > `Deployment` from the main menu.
2. Add wanted files by clicking `Add files`.
3. Change the file location from `.\` to `StartUp\Documents\`
4. Click the `Connect to Remote Machine` button (after couple of seconds, the column `Remote Status` should show `Missing`
5. Click the `Deploy` button and wait for `Remote Status` become `Same`

Now the file should be accessible from your application code:

```
ImagePath := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'LaunchImage_320x480.png');
if FileExists(ImagePath) then
  Image1.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ImagePath);
```

Compile your code run it in your iOS device or an iOS simulator. It should work and have fun!

**Notes:**

1. Filename is case sensitive on iOS.
2. Do not upload `.bmp` to iOS, because I do not think iOS supports bitmap.
3. The file location for an Andriod device is different. (but who cares)

Comment: This would add a 2nd set of the launch images. But a mobile application should be kept as small as possible.

Comment: Just to confirm, I am looking for a solution that will "reuse" the launch images Delphi includes/deploys. I do not want to deploy an extra copy of all my launch images. (However, it may turn up that is not possible. If that is the cause, I guess this would be the only solution left.)

Comment: @Tom I checked the default images of a firemonkey project on XE6, there is no file called `LaunchImage_` something. Most of them are `FM_*.png`. Where do you see these files?

Comment: Hmm... Checking deployment again, I can see remote name is different than my own name... Mayb be a "Doh!" moment, I will report back

Comment: Problem has been solved now - ability to see the acually file names using the code shows you were right about me having remote file names wrong :( everything works now. Upvoted your comment.